# Remove characters before dot

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im parsing html and now i got an NSString object that output like that:

```
 imageName is 4tmp.jpg
 imageName is 5tmp.jpg
 imageName is 6tmp.jpg
 imageName is 7tmp.jpg
 imageName is 8tmp.jpg
 imageName is 9tmp.jpg
```

And so on.

My code look like:

```
TFHpple *dataParseer = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:data];

    // 3
    NSString *dataXpathQueryString = @"//head/title";
    NSArray *dataNodes = [dataParseer searchWithXPathQuery:dataXpathQueryString];
    TFHppleElement *element = dataNodes[0];

    if ([element.text hasPrefix:@"Index of"]) {

        dataXpathQueryString = @"//tr/td/a";
        dataNodes = [dataParseer searchWithXPathQuery:dataXpathQueryString];

        for (TFHppleElement *element in dataNodes){

            NSString *imageName = [element objectForKey:@"href"];



        NSLog(@"imageName is %@", imageName);

    }
```

What i want is, remove characters before dot. So i can further concatenate it to correct url. How could i do that with `NSString`? Is there any method that can check characters before special symbol?

Comment: Have you looked for a method and tried it?

Comment: Its not finished. I just got output with strings needed to be cut. For example 9tmp.jpg should be .jpg. Easy as that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what exactly you want to get, but there are several ways to get values from string.

If you are working with path structures you can do something like this.

```
NSString *path = @"4tmp.jpg";

NSLog(@"1- %@",path.lastPathComponent);
NSLog(@"2- %@",[path.lastPathComponent stringByDeletingPathExtension]);
NSLog(@"3- %@",path.pathExtension);
```

Which will output something like

```
1- 4tmp.jpg
2- 4tmp
3- jpg
```

This will work obviously for more complex paths like `"something/4tmp.jpg"` in those cases the output will be the same as the one above

Comment: That is really helpful, actually, i didn't know such method exist. Thanks Benjamin!

Comment: There's no point to using `lastPathComponent` when `path` is already a "last path component".

Comment: In this specific case there is no need of using it, but as I explained later if you're working with more complex paths the output will be the same as the one showed with the simple example, and as OP is working with href, it's possible more complex paths are presented

Answer (score 2):

```
NSArray* stringComponents = [imageName componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
imageName = [stringComponents objectAtIndex:1];
```

Comment: I like your idea, but my app crash. It appears that it can't create an array with number of elements more then 0 (it can't reach object at index 1).

Comment: can you please tell me [element objectForKey:@"href"] have exact value and exact NSString class? Please try NSLog(@"%@  %@",[element objectForKey:@"href"],[[element objectForKey:@"href"] class]); and what is the result of that?

Comment: First of all there is more then 0 elements in array as it is indexed from 0, there is an object at index 0.
Try `[NSString substringFromIndex:[imageName rangeOfString@"."].location]`

Comment: I just tell u why my app crash, because of exception, trying to get an access of element beyond bounds. I will try, thank you!